# How do I pass multiple ID to jobCart page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've a job list page, displaying all jobs and there are checkbox next to each one, and there is an Add button at the bottom of the page, to add it to JobCart.php

I honestly don't know how to pass multiple record ID or single ID to jobCart.php
I want the when the user to click the button "Add" pass all selected ID to jobCart.php 
please help me

```
            <?php
        // adding JobsLists.php to this page to interact witht it.
          require ("../JobsLists.php");

        //Connect to DB
        //include_once("Project/CIEconn.php");
        $mysqlCON= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","CIE") or die(mysqli_connect_error()); 
        mysqli_select_db($mysqlCON,'CIE') or die ("no database");

        $ID = isset($_POST['Id']); // 1 2 

        if( isset($_POST['pick']) ){

      if( empty($ID) || $ID == 0 ){
      echo"<h4>   please choose something to move to your job list  </h4>";
     }else{

      // Code here ..
    // here here ONLY for TEST to check if I can interact eith jobLists.php
    addJob(); 

// to get all ID from each selected job
   $impid = implode("' , '" ,  $_POST['Id']);


     }

      }





        $sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM  Fiscal WHERE NoStudent > '0'  ";
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqlCON,$sqlCommand) or die(mysqli_error($mysqlCON)); 


        echo '
        <form action= "Fiscal.php"  method = "post">
        <table width ="100%" cellpadding ="4" border="1" >

        <tr>
        <th>Check </th>
        <th>Jobs Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th> No Students needed</th>
        <th>Due Date</th>
        </tr>';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ){

        // name = 'Id[]'
            echo "<tr>

        <td> <input type='checkbox'  name='Id[]'  value='". $row['Id'] ."' /> </td>


         <td> ". $row['JobName'] ." </td>
         <td> ". $row['Description'] ." </td>
         <td> ". $row['NoStudent'] . "</td>
        <td>". $row['DueDate'] ." </td>
        </tr>";


        }

        echo '
        </table>
        <br/>

        <div align="center">
        <input type="submit" name="pick" value="Add Job"  />

        <input type="reset" value="Clear Marks" />
        </div>

        </form>

        ';

        ?>

        <html>
        <head><title> Fiscal </title></head>
        <br>
        <body>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Do `echo $impid` and see what you're getting.

Comment: Thank u sir for ur reply, I got the ID for the two jobs I've . I think it's fine, but I  want now to pass them to jobCart.php,  I'm kinda new to this, I know how to pass single one, but not multiple

Comment: So after that what you're planning to do?

Comment: I want to add the selected jobs to jobCarts, so I need to pass the id to the other page.. if u wouldn't mind to direct me . ?

Comment: Store them in `$_SESSION` and redirect the user to *jobCart.php* using `header()`.

Comment: I want to decrement  the job number by "1" in the job.php and add the job to jobCart.php.  should i store the $impid in a '$_SESSION'

Comment: From where job number came into picture? Right now it's quite unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: the job page has these fields [ID , JobName , Job Descrption , numberOfJobs, DueDates] . so students who want to work, select a job or multiple jobs and click the button 'Add JOB', and the NumberOfJob must decrement by 1 and add this job to their jobCart.php

Comment: but If I know how to pass the "ID" to jobCart.php , I can do the rest.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, start session at the very top of your page, like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

And during the form processing store `$_POST['Id']` array to `$_SESSION` superglobal and redirect the user to jobCart.php page using `header()` function.

And one more thing, `$_POST['Id']` would be an array, so use `count()` function to see it's empty or not. So your code should be this:

```
// your code

if(isset($_POST['pick'])){

    if(count($_POST['Id'])){
        // store `$_POST['Id']` array to `$_SESSION` superglobal
        $_SESSION['ids'] = $_POST['Id'];

        // redirect the user to jobCart.php page
        header("Location: jobCart.php");
        exit();
    }

}

// your code
```

And in jobCart.php you can do something like this:

```
$impid = implode("','" , $_SESSION['ids']);

// rest of your code
```

Comment: thank u so much sir, I added a function in jobCart.php with 1 parameter, and passed $impid to this function, and I think it works .. but I'll try ur code, and give u a feedBack, THANK U SO MUCH Sir....

Comment: I'd like to ask u sir, is it possible to copy a job details to a different page like in JobLists.php without having a new table in mysql to store in it . ?

Comment: @Alotaibi Your question is unclear. Please explain what exactly you're trying to do?